# Spring boot: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter antMatchers permitAll not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have written a GET API with endpoint URL: /service/open/v1/test

Under WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, my httpSecurity is configured like:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/open/v1" + "/**").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

But getting **HttpStatus 403** while hitting the API. Kindly help.

Comment: Getting exception: org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Answer (score 1):

i think you covered the permitAll() setting by the second authorizeRequests();

try this

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/open/v1" + "/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Comment: Tried this one too.. no impact.